# SQL insert query with text value

Tags: database, sqlite

Is there a way that i can Insert this to database?

```
INSERT INTO Bill_Table (Patient_ID, [Med/Room], Bill, [Paid/UnPaid])
VALUES (13, 'Room ID' + (SELECT Room_ID 
                         FROM Room_Master 
                         WHERE [Room_No.] = 2),
        (SELECT Price  
         FROM Room_Type 
         WHERE Room_Type = 'Semi-Private'), 'UnPaid');
```

after the ' 13 ' on the values there is a string "Room ID" plus the selected "Room ID" but when I execute this only the Room ID inserted on the table is there a way I can put string text plus the select query

[image: The result here]

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because MySQL does not support square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code is the use of `+` for cocatenation, which does not work in SQLite. 
Instead use the `||` operator:

```
Insert Into Bill_Table (Patient_ID,[Med/Room],Bill,[Paid/UnPaid])
  values (
    13,
    'Room ID' || ' ' || (Select Room_ID from Room_Master where [Room_No.] = 2),
    (Select Price from Room_Type where Room_Type = 'Semi-Private'),
    'UnPaid'
  );
```

Comment: this is what I mean haha thank youuuu! sir this really help

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert Into Bill_Table (Patient_ID, [Med/Room], Bill,[Paid/UnPaid])
    Select 13, concat('Room ID', rm.Room_ID), rt.price, 'UnPaid'
    from Room_Master rm left join
         Room_Type rt
         on rt.Room_Type = 'Semi-Private'
    where rm.[Room_No.] = 2;
```

In SQLite, you would use the concat operator:

```
Insert Into Bill_Table (Patient_ID, [Med/Room], Bill,[Paid/UnPaid])
    Select 13, 'Room ID' || rm.Room_ID, rt.price, 'UnPaid'
    from Room_Master rm left join
         Room_Type rt
         on rt.Room_Type = 'Semi-Private'
    where rm.[Room_No.] = 2;
```

Comment: Sorry sir but there is no concat function on sqlite but Thank you sir btw

Comment: @DummyDummy . . . That is why there is a second answer for SQLite.  Your original question was not clear on the database you are using -- in fact, it was I who removed the MySQL tag.